# add textfield from an array plus simple text,to another textfield of an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two arrays with some textfields inside them.What i want to do is to put the text of textfield of the first array plus some simple text into the second array textfield.

**Example:**

```
var array1:Array=new Array();
var array2:Array=new Array();

var mytext1:TextField=new TextField();
var mytext2:TextField=new TextField();

mytext2.text="goodbye";

array1[0]=mytext1;
array2[0]=mytext2;

array1[0].text=array2[0].text+" hello";

trace(array1[0].text);
```

I believe this would trace:

```
goodbye hello
```

But instead it traces them in different rows:

```
goodbye         
hello
```

Comment: That code should give you the first result ("goodbye hello") ...

Comment: Ok i found why this happening.Its because textfields are multiline.But how can i achieve what i want and keep the textfields multiline???

Answer (score 0):

You will need te either make the text field bigger, or auto size it

easiest is to just set the width

```
mytext1.width = 350;
```

you can also adjust these parameters

```
mytext1.border = true;
mytext1.wordWrap = false;
```

to see the border, and to prevent folding line

you can look up more about text fields and how to autosize here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/

Comment: Well actually the problem was in embed fonts..I embed all fonts and the problem solved! Thanks for your answers though.